# Can I customize the popup window that is created with force:createRecord?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning

Right now, I got a component that creates an appointment record. Once you click create, the page displays the default record page for the Sales Appointment.

Is it possible to customize the popup to only display certain values? 
I'd simply like to just have it say "You have entered X, Y, Z - would you like to save" or something similar, not this window: [image]

Comment: you would have to create your own custom component for that

Comment: Any directions? :)

Comment: Check [lightning:editRecordForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_recordEditForm.htm), you will be able to customize it based on your needs

Comment: I'm afraid this is not really the thing I'm looking for. This seems to be for editing the form itself - these things don't apply to the popup? I don't wish to edit the form itself, but rather once you hit Save (from the form), this popup appears. I wish to edit the popup (screenshot)

Answer (score 2):

The [component documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_createRecord.htm) clearly states:

> Firing the force:createRecord event tells the app to use the standard
>   create record page. You can’t catch errors that occur there, or alter
>   the create page interface or behavior...

As mentioned in the comments, if you want to alter the behavior, you will have to create your own custom component(s) in order to acheve this behavior.

For staters, you will have to create your own Create Record button, you can then  leverage the [lightning:editRecordForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_recordEditForm.htm) component and embed it within a Modal Box using the [lightning:overlayLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_lightning_overlayLibrary.htm).

Once the record is saved, this component has  several events you can leverage to valdiate prior to creating the record, such as the The onsubmit action. Where you can prompt a confirmation, before saving the record. This will involve considerable amount of effort depending on your level of knowledge and familiarity with the lightning components and the framework itself.

Feel free to open a new post once you have started your implementation or hit any roadblocks.